# How can I allow lower case post codes in this regular expression?

Tags: regex, devexpress

This is the regular expression I use to validate UK post codes.

It works great except it only allows upper case post codes:

WA1 6EU is valid, wa1 6eu is not - But it should be!

How can I make the expression case-insensitive?

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```

UPDATE: I am using DEVXPRESS asp.net controls, which have Regular Expression validation avaiable on certain controls. : 
No case-insensitive key is allowed at the moment: http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q500302

I amended the expression as suggested below, but now upper case post codes are not valid - they were before:

```
^([A-PR-UWYZ0-9][a-pr-uwyz0-9][A-HK-Y0-9][a-hk-y0-9][AEHMNPRTVXY0-9][aehmnprtvxy0-9]?[ABEHMNPRVWXY0-9][abehmnprvwxy0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][ABD-HJLN-UW-Z][abd-hjln-uw-z]{2}|GIR 0AA)$
```

Comment: What language are you using? Can you change every letter in the regex to lowercase and just call your friendly neighbourhood `toLower()` before validating?

Comment: Some engines let you set a flag to ignore case. You could also repeat all the letters uppercase and lowercase, e.g., `A-Pa-p`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just enable the case insensitive flag `i`

Just wrap the expression as:

`/yourexpression/i`

See it on http://regex101.com/r/uX5rK9/1

Or you can use `ToUpperCase()` just before passing your string to the RegExp engine.

**EDIT**

This one should work if you can't set insensitive matching

`^([A-Pa-pR-Ur-uWwYyZz0-9][A-Ha-hK-Yk-y0-9][AaEeHhMmNnPpRrTtVvXxYy0-9]?[AaBbEeHhMmNnPpRrVvWwXxYy0-9]? {1,2}[0-9][AaBbD-Hd-hJjLlN-Un-uW-Zw-z]{2}|(G|g)(I|i)(R|r) 0[Aa]{2})$`

See it on http://regex101.com/r/yG4xD5/1

Comment: Well, that depends on what tool you're using, doesn't it.

Comment: @TomZych I think all regex flavours has `i` flag

Comment: You may be right. I don't know. I doubt you know for certain, either. There's an awful lot of software out there. Certainly the syntax you gave doesn't apply to everything.

Comment: Thanks - I need to spend some time on regular expressions!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: change `[A-PR-UWYZ0-9]` into `[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz0-9]`, and similarly for other `[...]`. This works regardless of engine.

Option 2: Turn on your regexp engine ignore case flag. You did not tag your post with a programming language, so we can't tell you how to do that, as it differs from language to language.

Comment: I've updated my original question - either I'm doing something wrong or your suggestion is not correct?

Comment: `[A-PR-UWYZ0-9][a-pr-uwyz0-9]` means an uppercase or a number, followed by a lowercase or a number: two characters, in all. What you want is `[A-PR-UWYZa-pr-uwyz0-9]`, uppercase or lowercase or number as one character.